# Microchip device support - MPLAB Snap supported or unsupported devices list

Tags: pic, microchip, programmer, mplab, pickit

Need to program and debug PIC and AVR MCU's so MPLAB Snap looks to be a very attractive option however:

> "it supports many of Microchip’s newer MCU offerings but not some legacy products" - [Microchip](https://www.microchipdeveloper.com/snap:start)

Maintaining a list of all supported products is too hard maybe, at least devices are not supported is known, I guess?
How can I determine if a device is not supported?
Is there like a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under [MPLABX IDE Release Notes](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/mplab-x-ide#tabs) is a complete list in `Readme for MPLAB Snap.htm`.

Comment: Wow, never looked inside the zip kept asking google. Much thanks just what I needed!!!

Comment: Good thing I decided to check, only 1 of the 46 SKU"s available at the local store works with SNAP!